# Have to call curl_close() twice before handle is closed and cookie jar can be read. Is this a bug?

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

I've been banging my head against the wall for hours trying to understand why cURL's cookie jar file was empty when I tried reading it. I just discovered that my code works if I call `curl_close()` twice instead of once, however, and I'm wondering if this is a bug with cURL.

Here's an example:

```
curl_close($chInfo['handle']);
var_dump(is_resource($chInfo['handle']));
```

That outputs `boolean true`. So, in other words, the handle isn't closed, despite the fact that I called `curl_close()`.

My next thought was that maybe it takes some time for the handle to be closed, so I tried using `sleep()` for a few seconds after the `curl_close()` call, but there wasn't any difference.

Out of desperation, I tried copying the `curl_close()` line, like this:

```
curl_close($chInfo['handle']);
curl_close($chInfo['handle']);
var_dump(is_resource($chInfo['handle']));
```

That outputs `boolean false`, meaning the handle is closed, and I am able to read from the cookie jar file (cURL writes the cookies to the file when the handle is closed).

So what's going on here? This seems an awful lot like a bug!

EDIT: I can't post my full code (you wouldn't want to read it anyway!), but here is a simplified example (note that only one url is fetched in this example, whereas in my real code `curl_multi` is utilized to fetch many URLs simultaneously):

```
$curlOptions = array(
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'Mozilla/5.001 (windows; U; NT4.0; en-US; rv:1.0) Gecko/25250101',
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5, // the number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 5, // the maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, // TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => 1,
    CURLOPT_REFERER        => null,
    CURLOPT_POST           => 0,  // GET request by default
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => '', // no POST data by default
    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT    => 1, // allows the request header to be retrieved
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => 1, // returns the response header along with the page body
    CURLOPT_URL            => 'http://www.example.com/',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      => __DIR__ . '/cookie.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     => __DIR__ . '/cookie.txt'
);
```

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOptions); // set the options for this handle

$mh = curl_multi_init();
$responses = array();
curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch); // add the handle to the curl_multi object

do
{
    $result   = curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    $activity = curl_multi_select($mh);    // blocks until there's activity on the curl_multi connection (in which case it returns a number > 0), or until 1 sec has passed

    while($chInfo = curl_multi_info_read($mh))
    {
        $chStatus = curl_getinfo($chInfo['handle']);

        if($chStatus['http_code'] == 200) // if the page was retrieved successfully
        {
            $response = curl_multi_getcontent($chInfo['handle']); // get the response

            curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $chInfo['handle']); // remove the curl handle that was just completed
            curl_close($chInfo['handle']);                    // close the curl handle that was just completed (cookies are saved when the handle is closed?)
            curl_close($chInfo['handle']);

            var_dump(is_resource($chInfo['handle']));
        }
        else // request failed
        {
            echo 'Error: Request failed with http_code: ' . $chStatus['http_code'] . ', curl error: ' . curl_error($chInfo['handle']). PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
} while ($running > 0);

curl_multi_close($mh);
```

If you run the above code, the output will be

```
boolean false
```

Indicating that the handle is closed. However, if you remove the second call to `curl_close()`, then the output changes to

```
boolean true
```

Indicating the handle is *not* closed.

Comment: This is really strange. I never had such an issue and I'm working with cURL quite often. What is your PHP version? Are you okay with sharing the cURL execution?

Comment: @ailvenge I'm using PHP version 5.4.12. I posted example code for you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am curious why you use curl_close instead curl_multi_close? On every other place you use curl_multi_..., i think it is logical to use curl_multi_close too. This is just a tougth..

Comment: @bksi I use `curl_close()` to close a handle after it has successfully retrieved a page. I use `curl_multi_close()` after all of the handles have finished processing. The example code just fetches one URL, but my real code fetches many URLs simultaneously using `curl_multi`.

Comment: This part of code i see, is showing me that you use same $ch to do the requests. I'm not sure why you use it this way. Here is the simple example of using curl_multi_add_handle: http://se2.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-close.php They use different curl instances to add handlers.

Comment: @bksi This is just a very simplified example. In my real code I have an array of cURL handles, I don't use the same one for multiple request (each request has it's own handle. once a request is completed, then I close the handle. once all the requests are completed, I call `curl_multi_close()`).

Comment: @bksi I can't call `curl_multi_close()` until *all* of the cURL requests have finished processing. I call `curl_multi_remove_handle()` and `curl_close()` for the individual cURL handles once they have finished processing, then I call `curl_multi_close()` once *all* of the handles have finished processing.

Comment: But you don't use $ch to close the instance as is in the example. curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch); curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch); then you should use curl_close($mh, $ch);

Comment: @bksi `$chInfo['handle']`, where `$chInfo = curl_multi_info_read($mh)`, is equal to `$ch`.

Comment: But you use same variable to init the curl. As i said in my first post, i don't think this is good idea (else if you know that they don;t use shared memory, or memory pointers inside the curl stuff). I would use $ch[] instead $ch.

Comment: @bksi In my full code I have a `for` loop that has `$ch = curl_init();` then more code and then `curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch)`. Is that not valid (if so, thanks for pointing it out!)? In either case, with the example I posted here, only one handle is being created and the problem still exists.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is actually a bug in PHP's curl. Looking at the PHP source code, I'm getting the impression that there's some reference counting going awry, but I can't be sure. Might be worth actually raising this as an issue with PHP, and seeing what the maintainers say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not realy a bug, but just the way it works. If you look at the source code you can see what is happening.

At first you open the handle with `$ch = curl_init();` and looking at the source in `ext\curl\interface.c` you can see that internally it sets `ch->uses = 0;`

Then you call `curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);` and looking at `ext\curl\multi.c` this method does `ch->uses++;`. At this point `ch->uses==1`

Now the last part, looking at `curl_close($chInfo['handle']);`, again in `ext\curl\interface.c` it has the following code:

```
if (ch->uses) {
    ch->uses--;
} else {
    zend_list_delete(Z_LVAL_P(zid));
}
```

So the first attempt to close it will decrease `ch->uses` and the second attempt it will actually close it.

This internal pointer only increases when using `curl_multi_add_handle` or when using `curl_copy_handle`. So I guess the idea was for `curl_multi_add_handle` to use a copy of the handle and not the actual handle.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you for delving into the source code to figure out the cause behind this odd behavior! It seems strange to me that the developers of cURL would make it that way. The fact that the cURL handle **must** be closed in order for the cookie jar/file to be read makes me feel like this is a bug, because when using multi_curl that means you **have** to close the handle twice. Thanks for getting to the bottom of it!

Comment: Well the oposite of `curl_multi_add_handle` seems to be `curl_multi_remove_handle` and that does `--ch->uses`. It looks like they expected somebody to add the handle to multi curl to be processed and after it was removed they could still access the handle.

So instead of `close;close;` you could also use `remove;close` and then it seems perfectly logical to me. Anyway, thanks for the rep :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is no issue. When using `multi-curl` you don't need to call `curl_close`. Instead, you have to call `curl_multi_remove_handle` on each used handle. So the `curl_close` call(s) in your code is redundant.

See examples of proper `multi-curl` flow here: [1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-add-handle.php), [2](http://code.google.com/p/rolling-curl/source/browse/trunk/RollingCurl.php).

Comment: According to the documentation, the cookie jar file is not updated until `curl_close()` is called. Through my own testing, this seems to be the case. As mentioned in my question, I have to call it twice before the cookie jar file can be read, so clearly there is an issue.

Comment: @Nate Are you using one cookie jar file for all curl requests?

Comment: No, I'm using a separate file for each handle.

Comment: I have worked with `multi-curl` many times and I never experienced any problem with saving/loading cookies. See my example of `multi-curl` implementation here (sorry for the plug): https://github.com/hindmost/rolling-curl-mini

Answer (score -1):

The 'handle' is not closed in the loop 
after the loop you can remove the handles

```
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
    /* this is not suppose to be required but the remove sometimes fails to close the connection */
    curl_close($ch1); 
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
    curl_close($ch2);

if you set up your connections as an array you can remove them through a separate loop after the main loop.

    /* init and add connection */
    foreach ($multi_urls as $i => $url) 
    {
        $ch[$i] = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_multi_add_handle ($mh, $ch[$i]);
    }

    main loop {
        ....
    }

    /* remove and close connection */
    foreach($ch AS $i => $conn)
    { 
       curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
       curl_close($ch[$i]);
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

I think there is only 1 mistake after looking into the code i.e.

```
while($chInfo = curl_multi_info_read($mh))
```

change with

```
while($chInfo == curl_multi_info_read($mh))
```

Comment: This is wrong.  The OP's code is correct: he assigns the result of the call to a variable and checks whether the variable is NULL.  If the call returned a non-NULL value, the loop continues.